# python3 threads machine learning

Tags: python, multithreading

Can anybody help me out,

```
import threading, time, sys

class Counter:

    def count_x(self, value):
        for _ in range(100000000):
            value += 1
        return value 

    def func_A(self):
        self.some_value = get_the_value_from_the_file()

    def func_B(self):
        print(self.some_value)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.func_A()
            self.count_x(self.some_value)
            self.func_B()


app = Counter()
app.run()
```

Got a code like above, i know it's not very good practice i think.
But i need to make it working like it:

```
first loop:
 func_A - gets value from the file 
 func_count_x = gets value as a parameter and starts doing math on that value
 func_B - prints the value from first loop taken by func_A
2nd loop:
 func_A - gets new value from the file 
 func count_x = is asked if it finished doing math from 1st loop: NO (don't give new value to that function and let it finishing doing math with value from 1st loop)
 func_B - prints value from first loop taken by func_A (beacuse count_x has no answer)

3rd loop:
 func_A - gets new value from the file 
 func count_x = is asked if it finished doing math from 1st loop: YES so now value = answer from that function, count_x gets new value from 3rd loop func_A and it starts doing math on that new value
 func_B - prints newest value from produced by count_x

4th loop:
 func_A - gets new value from the file 
 func count_x = is asked if it finished doing math from 3st loop: NO (don't give new value to that function and let it finishing doing math with value from 3rd loop)
 func_B - prints newest value from produced by count_x

5th loop:
 func_A - gets new value from the file 
 func count_x = is asked if it finished doing math from 3st loop: YES (YES so now value = answer from that function, count_x gets new value from 5rd loop func_A and it starts doing math on that new value)
 func_B - prints newest value from produced by count_x

and go on and go on
```

and just to be sure, in my program there is like 20-30 more functions like func A and B so i don't think i can create threads for every function?
it's for ML so i need to make that the answer from my model is overwriting last answer only when function is called and only when it has an answer

So my normal program is running like it:
 1. Get frames from camera
 2. Do some stuff on that frame
 3. Run my ML model on that frame and return the answer
 4. Do some other stuff
 5. Print answer from model on current frame
and i need it to make that the answer from model is in separate thread so it can can run smoothly so the answer from model is written only when it has an answer so the program doesn't wait for that answer just like in the example i made.

thanks a lot guys :)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. But instead of explicitly waiting for 5 secs, you could check if the elapsed time was 5 secs and if not wait, say 0.1 secs. Use `start = datetime.datetime.now()` and `(datetime.datetime.now()-start).total_seconds()` for this.

Comment: that has nothing to do with my question?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly your problem is. Which parts do you want to run concurrently? Your desired output explicitly talks about sleeping 5 seconds, why do you need to do this concurrently? Your Counter doesn't count anything, what do you mean by "start again else still count"? Are you aware of the basic ``threading`` interface, such as ``Lock`` and ``Event``?

Comment: I'm afraid you stripped down your example too much. The code you provide will _always_ wait for 5 secs after `func_A` and before `func_B`. I assumed what you actually want to do is check if the execution time of `func_B` followed by `func_A` is more than 5 secs. You can do that with the method I suggested. If that's not what you want to do, you have to be more clear about it.

Comment: so i changed the example a little bit i hope now you can understand it better 
@MisterMiyagi i mean like do you have an answer from function count_x then return it, if function is still counting/sleeping or whatever it is doing, don't do anything just go to the next function so count/sleep is still running 
No not really also, so i am looking for help here

Comment: Is it that you only want to run `func_B` after `count_x` and `func_A` have finished? If so have a look at `threading.Event` and `threading.Barrier`.

Comment: so i want to run it something liek that func_A > ask count_x if it has done doing the math if yes then overwrite value and here is new math to be done if it still counting let the function count and go to function_B > func_B and start again from beginning

Comment: Your descriptions are ambiguous and very hard to follow. Please take the time to *clearly* describe your problem in proper English.

Comment: maybe now you can understand what i could get help with :)

Comment: Sounds as if two instances of [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) could work. Start your ml thread and let it do the following in an infinite loop: wait for new entry in the main_to_ml queue; fetch it; calculate response; put response into ml_to_main queue. In your main thread during first run, put value into main_to_ml queue. In subsequent runs check if ml_to_main queue contains response, if yes take it and put new value into main_to_ml queue, if not just continue. I don't have the time to put together a complete implementation, hope this still helps though.

Comment: @Swenzel, thanks man, after a lot of google i know how to use your solution and it's working perfectly :) thank you again